# How to use a dynamic selector in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-6

In a Ruby on Rails 6 environment, I need to hide all the html elements, and show only those having a specific id. But I am not able to correctly specify the selector, and the following xquery fragment doesn't run:

```
/* the @tag variable contains #xyz value */

$("#main-center .main-element").hide();

$(@tag).show();
```

I also tried Ruby interpolation `$("#{@tag}")` and `$(<% @tag %>)` with no success.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: The result of the preprocessor should put the single or double quotes around the selector.  Similar to how `$(#main-center .main-element)` would be invalid, `$(#xyc)` is also invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the selector in quotes (single or double):

`$('<%= @tag %>').show();`

or

`$("<%= @tag %>").show();`

Comment: This seems to be the right way, but ```$("#xyz")``` fires while ```$("<%= @tag %>")``` doesn't!

Comment: Does your `@tag` variable really have the value `#xyz` or just `xyz`? Perhaps you can peek on what your preprocessor outputs for `@tag`. You can try adding `console.log("Value of @tag is: <%= @tag %>")` beforehand and see what you get on the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Ruby guy but assuming Ruby is preprocessing this file before it hits the browser, I believe you need:

`$("{@tag}").show();`

Javascript needs the quotes because the selector is a string.